# Matlab gamfit and gampdf functions written in C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, matlab, gamma-distribution

I am wondering if someone has already implemented the two Matlab functions [gamfit](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/gamfit.html) and [gampdf](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2011b/toolbox/stats/gampdf.html) in C, C++ or objective-C. I figured I would ask before I go ahead and implement them myself.

Answer (score 0):

Hope those links to c source code may be of help:

http://www.mymathlib.com/functions
http://www.mymathlib.com/functions/probability/gamma_distribution.html
http://www.mymathlib.com/c_source/functions/probability/densities/gamma_density.c

Note: You should check for license, only reference I could find there was *"Copyright © 2004 RLH. All rights reserved."*

You may also check Boost libraries:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/dist/dist_ref/dists/gamma_dist.html